# Explaining extends

Tags: java, oop, extends

so i have my programming exam this winter and one of my assignments is to explain what extends is without using a programming example.

Now i know what it is but i find it hard to explain with words how would you explain it? Like you extends which means you are a part of the class and can add additional information to the class that only your object can see i.e a `Plane` **extends** `Vehicle` but has its own methods called take off that allows it to fly.

How would you guys explain `extends`?

Comment: So, you want us to just straight-up do your assignment for you? Back in my day, which wasn't even all that long ago, that would probably have run afoul of our honor code.

Comment: Im not trying to make you do my assignment i am trying to find insperation to what i can say.

Comment: G "inheritance analogy" maybe?

Comment: Read this, basics of Inheritance which helps you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: What kind of inspiration? What does it mean to extend a class? What are the characteristics of an extended class? What does extending a class allow you to do? What kinds of work does extending a class avoid? Etc.

Comment: the difference between that an implementing

Comment: @MarcRasmussen ... That should be obvious, but aside from that, if that's part of your question, make it part of the question. Can't you list the differences yourself? It doesn't seem like you're putting any particular effort into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extends` keyword in Java has several roles, and it depends on what you `extends`. If `C` is the entity you wish to extend.

- You cannot extend it at all if `C` is a non `abstract` class and is `final`;
- If `C` is a non-final, non-abstract class:

  - you can extend it so as to add constructors;
  - you can override any methods of `C` which are not declared final;
  - you can define additional instance variables, methods etc.
- If `C` is an abstract class, and you provide a concrete (ie, non abstract) implementation of it:

  - you *must* provide constructors which call this abstract class' constructors -- *all of them*;
  - you *must* provide implementations of methods which are declared `abstract` in the extended class;
  - you *may* override implementations of methods of this class which are not `abstract`;
  - you *cannot* override implementations of methods in this class which are declared final;
  - you *may* add additional constructors, instance variables etc;
- If `C` is an interface:

  - you can only declare an `interface` extending another; you cannot implement a class extending an interface (that is `implements`).

And, more generally, you can implement several interfaces but only extend one class/abstract class (Java does not have multiple inheritance).

Answer certainly to be edited, feel free to add comments/questions/etc

Answer (score 1):

You can find examples all around you.....
eg:Animals and different variety of animals
Vehicles, with different vehicles having some common properties and some specific properties.
Shapes with common properties like area, perimeter etc, where different shapes calculate these functions differently.

Comment: I've been teaching C++ to some beginners, and finding a wheeled vehicle analogy works quite well. I often go back to the same analogy to explain ideas.